# Is it possible to add audio to the viewport to make animating voices easier?

Tags: animation

Is it possible to add audio to a scene that plays like in Davinci Resolve when you scroll through a clip in the sequencer with your mouse at your own pace, but instead in Blender in the 3D view so it's easier to animate voices?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution that is possible to my issue is to just load the audio file into the sequencer and it plays when the sequencer plays.